# blender 4.0 AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_ids'

Tags: python, outliner

I upgraded blender to version 4.0, but I can't use the code `bpy.context.selected_ids` in version 4.0. The console gives an error `AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_ids'`.

Please help me, thank you guys.

```
import bpy


def ADD_HT_outliner(self, context):
    print(bpy.context.selected_ids)


def register():
    bpy.types.OUTLINER_HT_header.append(ADD_HT_outliner)
```

Comment: it must be in the outliner context to work. If not this attribute is not defined/associated to the context.

Comment: It should work. How exactly does the error happen ? BTW you can use the passed context with `print(context.selected_ids)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even using `print(context.selected_ids)`, the same error will still occur

Comment: I just want to get the id of the selected object in the UI. Isn't your code supposed to report an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in blender 4.0

```
import bpy

scr = bpy.context.screen
areas = [area for area in scr.areas if area.type == 'OUTLINER']
regions = [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

with bpy.context.temp_override(area=areas[0], region=regions[0], screen=scr):
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_ids:
        print(f"Selected: {obj.name} - {type(obj)}")
```